# Inverse image sheaf functor: proving $(f^\ast P)_x=P_{f(x)}$

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory

Let $P$ be a $\mathsf{Set}$-valued presheaf and let $f^\ast:\mathsf{PSh}(Y)\rightarrow \mathsf{PSh}(X)$ be the (topological) inverse image sheaf functor, defined on objects as the filtered colimit
$$(f^\ast P)(U)=\varinjlim_{V\supset f(U)}PV,\;\;\;V\text{ open}$$
I'm trying to prove $(f^\ast P)_x=P_{f(x)}$ by abstract nonsense. So just writing definitions down ($U$ is open):
$$(f^\ast P)_x= \varinjlim_{U\ni x}f^\ast P(U)=\varinjlim_{U\ni x} \varinjlim_{V\supset f(U)}PV$$
I *think* I should say something along the lines of "since colimits commute with colimits, the RHS is equal to $\varinjlim_{V\supset f(U):U\ni x}PV$, which is itself equal to $\varinjlim_{V\ni f(X)}PV$."

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to formalize the use of the "colimits commute with colimits theorem", nor how to make the leap from $V\supset f(U):U\ni x$ to $V\ni f(x)$.

How do I proceed?

Comment: Do $x$ (and $U,V$) live in some topological spaces?

Comment: The only abstract nonsense proof I am aware of is restricted to _sheaves_ (not presheaves), and it is based on the fact that the composite of two left adjoints is the left adjoint of the composite (of the right adjoints).

Comment: @Berci yes - $x$ is a point in $X$, $U$ is an open subset of $X$, and $V$ is an open subset of $Y$. $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is an arrow in $\mathsf{Top}$.

Comment: @ZhenLin could you post this proof as an answer? I'll accept it if nobody supplies a more general one.

Comment: @ZhenLin do you think some kind of cofinality argument for the inclusion of a proper sub-poset into the poset of open sets containing $f(x)$ might make my attempt work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an abstract nonsense proof for *sheaves*.

Given a continuous map $f : X \to Y$, we get a functor $f_* : \mathbf{Sh} (X) \to \mathbf{Sh} (Y)$, defined on objects by $f_* A (V) = A (f^{-1} V)$. The assignment $f \mapsto f_*$ is clearly functorial. But a point $x$ in $X$ is given by a continuous map $x : 1 \to X$, so $f_* x_* = f (x)_*$; hence $x^* f^* \cong f (x)^*$, because the left adjoint of the composite is the composite of the left adjoints. But $x^*$ (resp. $f (x)^*$) is precisely the functor taking a sheaf on $X$ (resp. $Y$) to the stalk at $x$ (resp. $f (x)$).

Comment: Elegant proof. Is the assignment $f\mapsto f_\ast$ literally part of a functor though? The domain category should be $\mathsf{Top}$, but what would the codomain category be?

Comment: In fact, this proof works fine with presheaves too. The functor $f^*$ (the left adjoint of $f_*$) is not the same for sheaves and presheaves (one needs to sheafify the second to get the first), but if $x_*:Set\rightarrow PSh(X)$ is the skyscraper sheaf functor, then $x^*$ is still the stalk at $x$.

Comment: @Arrow The codomain category would be the (very large) category of (large) categories. It is literally a functor the way I define it.